# Why does this code return undefined and how to make this code work

Tags: javascript, promise

Request to the api successfully return the data as expected. The data from api is saved to 'fact' variable. The problem is that the 'getData' function returns promise which is expected to resolve 
the data, instead it returns undefined.

```
const getData = num => {
  let fact;
  if (Array.isArray(num)) {
    fetch(`http://numbersapi.com/${num[0]}/${num[1]}/date`)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        fact = data;
      });
  } else if (num.math === true) {
    fetch(`http://numbersapi.com/${num.val}/math`)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        fact = data;
      });
  } else {
    fetch(`http://numbersapi.com/${num}`)
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        fact = data;
      });
  }
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(fact);
  });
};

getData([1, 26]).then(val => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

Comment: "return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(fact);
  });" that's not how it works... like... at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch is a promise based api, it returns a promiss, and you don't need to wrap fetch in promise.

You could prepare the url string in the if checks, and then use it in the fetch call.

**Example**

```
const getData = num => {
  let url;
  if (Array.isArray(num)) {
    url = `http://numbersapi.com/${num[0]}/${num[1]}/date`;

  } else if (num.math === true) {
    url = `http://numbersapi.com/${num.val}/math`;

  } else {
    url = `http://numbersapi.com/${num}`
  }
  return fetch(url);
};

getData([1, 26]).then(response => {
  console.log(response.text());
});
```